# CentOS 7 - Load settings for iptables at OS startup

Tags: boot, iptables, upstart, firewalld

I would like to load the settings below for `iptables` on CentOS 7 at OS startup using a bash script.

**How can I do this?**

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -I OUTPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.9:22
```

**NOTE:** I know the default CentOS 7 firewall service is `firewall-cmd` and I don't want to remove it (use the `iptables` service instead). I am trying this approach because apparently the `firewall-cmd` does not work for the above settings (see thread [firewall-cmd - add-forward-port don't work](https://superuser.com/q/1474254/195840) para mais informações).

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 1):

First you use

```
iptables-save >/wherever/iptables.save
```

Then

```
iptables-restore </wherever/iptables.save
```

Then you have to know if your linux is systemd or init

If its systemd then you can create a fake service to load the file.

You could try

```
chkconfig iptables on
```

Then you need to locate and replace the existing iptables saved file.

I would try

find / -iname "iptables.save"

and see if you can find it that way.

See Also
https://serverfault.com/a/739465/206895

To be continued....